# Altium tracks being unrouted

Tags: altium

While fixing another problem, Im noticing that some of traces are broken. The board was 90% routed, and now some of those completed traces are incomplete, like as if there was a small break in them.

What can cause that ? And how do I stop it ?

**edit**
I attached this image to show what I meant. I couldn't wait for an answer, so I had to manually connect the broken traces again, so for this image, I broke the connection to show what it looked it.

The trace was routed in full before, and then after some "change", a few of my traces looked like the image below.

[image]

Comment: How about a screen cap? Broken where, exactly? How do you know?

Comment: I've already rerouted it, but I'll show by manually cutting it.

Comment: the movement of "rooms" by accident may cause this, if your room movement method drags all components and objects (traces) with it. Maybe the traces belonged to different rooms and were separate at one point

Answer (score 1):

The location that broke in is the interface between two rooms. I'd guess you moved one of the rooms, which will take the room components and trace segments with it.

To prevent accidentally moving rooms, you can lock them when you're done with them, or you can route a room at a time, place them on the board, then route the actual exit from each room into the adjacent room.